# Having difficulty getting a div positioned properly over a div that has overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css

Some background: I have a site header and created some jQuery code that displays a div (headerAdminPanel) when one clicks on another div (either workspaceSelectNav or accountActionsContainer) which will essentially be a menu with various options within it.  I am having some trouble getting this headerAdminPanel panel div to display properly because the header has a div with overflow:hidden in it and z-index positioning does not appear to be the answer (unless I am doing something wrong).

Here is my HTML code:
http://jsfiddle.net/user1032334/NY75B/2/

Comment: Could you distill this to the simplest possible scenario where you observe this problem? Also, consider posting an example (including your jQuery) to [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if we have your entire code for this section. But you have 2 extra closing `</div>` tags in  your code. Invalid HTML *could* be the cause of your problem (and many more!).
**Line 19 & 20 have an extra `</div>` tag.**

[Check out this JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/3hYVD/) <-- This is your code with the 2 extra closing tags. (Commented)
[Check out this JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/3hYVD/3/) <-- This is your code **WITHOUT** the 2 extra tags.

Comment: Thanks.  I added in the JS so you can see what I am looking at.  If you click on the Workspace name or username panel, you will see the div display on the left.  I need this div to show its full height outside the white div if that makes sense.  It should display over the orange "5" [link]http://jsfiddle.net/user1032334/NY75B/1/

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Just entered it back in, looks like it saved now.

Answer (score 1):

Only elements with `position:relative;`,`position:absolute;`, or `position:fixed;` are affected by `z-index`.

Perhaps this will help:

`#workspaceSelectNav { position:relative; z-index:whatever;}`

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be to simply add the height of the submenu into your header so that the overflow doesn't cut it off when it displays. You could always apply a negative margin to the bottom if you don't want the extra height to push the content below down.